# VB.net strange textbox behavior

Tags: vb.net, textbox, inline-editing

A customer of mine is having a problem with a text box. When he clicks on the string in the text box the cursor always jumps to the end of the string. This is a standard VB.net 2005 text box with multi-line true. On my development machine it works correctly. I click in the middle of a string and can edit where I click. Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

He has run the program both under terminal server and locally on his lap top and has the same problem.

TIA,
John

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to observe the user? For example, the user might be pressing shift-tab when they are past the text-box, and refering to that as "clicking" the text box.

You can always force behavior like:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to allow the user to place the cursor anywhere in the string so selectionstart = 0 would not work. I am sure he is not holding down other keys. Thanks again.